# Is this a proper use of Jenkins?

Tags: php, .net, jenkins

We're a web development shop using PHP or .Net. Here's the proposed path for development:

```
Developer -> SVN Server -> Jenkins Server -> Dev Server
```

1. A developer commits or creates a tag to the SVN Server
2. Either a commit or tag triggers a job on Jenkins asynchronously
3. The job on Jenkins will run a svn update (or clear destination space, then svn export) on Dev Server bringing the code in from the SVN Server
4. For .Net, after having copied the code, I need to compile it using aspnet_compile

My question is two fold, is this a proper use of Jenkins? And, if I were to compile .Net using aspnet_compile.exe, would installing a slave on the Microsoft OS be the way to go (to enable this)?

**To futher the answer:**

Check the Restrict where this project can be run, select slave.

Comment: it sounds like you want a continuous deployment solution.  Where in certain triggers (commit/tag) will initiate a build in Jenkins, where it will pull the source from your SVN server, run any tests, compile the code, and then deploy it.  Do you use any sort of build process like ANT or Maven?  Jenkins can be configured to use these tools to completely automate the process for you.

Comment: @thescientist No build process or unit testing (yet), this is straight up PHP. Since the SVN Server is the point of contact to our architecture, I need to put the files on the appropriate server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a fairly standard build / deploy workflow and therefore a good use of Jenkins, but I'd suggest doing step 4 as part of your Jenkins build and then deploying the compiled artifacts to your dev server also using Jenkins.  This way you'll be able to have Jenkins report compilation problems as build failures and have the ability to run tests against the compiled code as part of the Jenkins job, per @thescientist's comment.

If your Jenkins master is running on an operating system other than Windows, you can use a Windows slave to do the compilation.  You could even have the slave process running on your dev server to make deployment easier; I wouldn't recommend this for a production setup, but it's OK for dev.

Here are some links which may help you:

[Running Jenkins on Windows](http://yakiloo.com/setup-jenkins-and-windows/)

[Building ASP.NET code with Jenkins](http://game-linchpin.com/2012/04/installing-jenkins-as-continuous-integration-builder-on-windows.html)

[Jenkins and PHP](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+and+PHP)

Comment: Our master will be on Linux. Does this mean that Linux, using MSBuild, can compile .Net? Or is the slave (on Windows) that is  going to compile it? If so, how do I configure the plugin on the slave?

Comment: The slave will do the compilation, but the MSBuild plugin configuration is set up on the master.  You just need to set up an MSBuild.exe location that matches where the tool is located on your slave.

Comment: just wanted to point out that on the master, I call a batch file on the slave. This batch file calls aspnet_compiler with appropriate parameters.